# How can I use a GitLab repository as the backend for a google cloud load balancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab

I have a full html website in a GitLab repository and have been using a gcloud bucket as the backend for my website. How can I switch from using the bucket as the backend of my load balancer to using the GitLab repo master as the backend?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [Internet Network Endpoint Group](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/internet-neg-concepts) as backend of your HTTPS load balancer.